# At which point in a web application can I call one method only once every 24 hours?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to run a code only once every 24 hours.

So, in Global.asax file: I try to put in `Application_Start` but when a Session ends the code is called again. I try to put in a static variable but I had the same issue. So, where can I put the code to run only once every 24 hours in my web app?

Comment: I think that a web app is not the right tool for this. Why not a Windows Service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no reliable way to host [`recurring background tasks in ASP.NET applications`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx). The correct way to do that is to host the code in a Windows Service or a console application that is scheduled to execute at regular intervals using the Windows scheduler.

Comment: My goal with the question was to know (to check) what I feared: like you said "There's no reliable way [...]". Anyway, thank you! Let's go to Windows Service! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Why is this a web application? If you want to run this once a day isn't this more suited to a proper application like a Windows Service?

If you HAVE to use a web application, you're going to need to store the last run date and time somewhere, like a config file or database. Once that is complete, you can set up a scheduled task to call a link on your site on a daily basis and it should just work, but you've then added a dependency on another external service.